# How to substitute all the contents inside double quotes in vim using %s?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a config file with usernames and passwords like this:

```
username = "someuser"; password = "blabla";
username = "anotheruser"; password = "tralala";
```

Sometimes the config is not very organized, so we can have the symbol "=" closer or with double space, like

```
username=  "foo"
```

So, in vim, how can I replace everything with the username and password following some magic regex expression in order to have everything like:

```
username = "no_user"; password = "no_password";
```

Note that my main goal is to replace the content inside the double quotes. The organization is just a plus. Thanks.

Comment: You should edit your question to reflect that "organization is just a plus".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the organization easily with capture groups:

```
:%s/\(username\|password\)\s*=\s*\("[^"]*"\)/\1 = \2/g
```

If you want to just change the values it is best done via 2 separate substitutions.

```
:%s/username\zs\s*=\s*"[^"]*"/ = "no_user"
:%s/password\zs\s*=\s*"[^"]*"/ = "no_password"
```

Note I am using `\zs` to start the match after the label to avoid a longer command.

For more help see:

```
:h :s
:h /\(
:h /\zs
:h pattern
```

Comment: Can I have another question? I'm trying now to replace this: parameter = true; by parameter = false; but I'm not finding the exact regex. Can you help me?

Comment: @user179589 `:%s/parameter\zs\s*=\s*true/ = false` I would recommend you take sometime and get familiar with regex and `:s`. Using regex's in Vim is a wonderful way to do this. Please read `:h pattern-overview` if you are already familiar with regex's and want to learn Vim's dialect. Otherwise I suggest you look at [vimregex](http://vimregex.com/) and [learn regex the hard way](http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/). With some practice regex's are a great tool to have in your toolbox and will serve you well

Comment: Sure, I'm trying to study, but I needed this fast because I'm at work. Anyway, thank you a lot for the help. Very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
:%s:username *= *"[^"]\+":username = "no_user":g
:%s:password *= *"[^"]\+":password = "no_passwd":g
```

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the answer, but actually my main goal is to replace all the username and passwords. The organization is just a plus. Can you help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: This does not answer the original question.